# vncserver -compatiblekbd fails with unrecognized option

Tags: emacs, vnc

I found that when I connect to my computing cluster via vnc `Alt-x` is not recognized correctly as`M-`. I tried

```
vncserver -compatiblekbd
```

but I get

```
Unable to start Xvnc, exiting
```

Actually once my session was started and in the log I found:

```
Fatal server error:
Unrecognized option: -compatiblekbd`
```

How can I pass this option to vncserver and get the correct mapping  of  `Alt+x` ?

[image: screenshot of the effect of pressing Alt+x]

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the output from this command to see if your setup supports that switch `compatiblekbd`.

```
$ Xvnc -help
```

From the man page for Xvnc:

```
-compatiblekbd
    Set META and ALT keys to the same X modifier flag, as in the original 
    version of Xvnc by AT&T labs (TightVNC-specific).
```

It sounds like this is a switch to Xnvc, not `vncserver`, and that switch may be dependent on different back-ends, specifically just the TightVNC implementations.

#### References

- [TightVNC Xvnc(1) Manual Page](http://www.tightvnc.com/Xvnc.1.php)

Comment: it is not there

Comment: @simona - so I would conclude that you don't have that switch then. Can you get a screenshot of what happens when you type Alt-X on the compute cluster. There can be a variety of reasons as to the wrong key getting sent.

Comment: here it is the screenshot

Comment: @simona - yeah that doesn't help. What does Alt-X do in Xterm?

Comment: Hmmm...is there a difference between Left Alt + X and Right Alt + X?  There may be a keymap that interprets Right Alt as AltGr...a key used to input non-English characters (like ñ, which is Right alt + n on my system)

Comment: @slm in the xterm Alt-X outputs the same character as in the screenshot.

Comment: @samiam the behaviour is the same, same character

Comment: If you don't need to input accented/non-ASCII characters, `setxkbmap us` (run it in an xterm on the X server) can disable all international characters, and *might* resolve your issue.

Comment: @samiam 'XKB extension not present on localhost:80.0'